# Craft Calendars Performance Issues

Tags: php, calendar

Is anyone experiencing performance issues with the Craft Calendars plugin. We have loaded in 900 events (some with recurrence rules and most without) and we are having issues with trying to pull the calendar events:

```
$params = array(
        'calendarId' => 1,
        'dateRangeStart' => craft()->calendars_eventData->DT($fromDate),
        'dateRangeEnd' => craft()->calendars_eventData->DT($toDate),
        'order' => 'date asc'
    );

    $events = craft()->calendars_eventData->getEventDataCriteriaModel($params)->find();
```

But we are having timeouts trying to generate the data (times out after 10 minutes!).

I’ve done some profiling and the issues seem to be going into the recurrence and just the sheer volume of db and yii CActiveFinder function calls, so I'm unsure whether this module can cater for this number of events in an efficient manner?